Distributional visualization of small discrete values
I have barely under 40 small integer counts per measurement type from a study subject. The counts start from zero, and the distributions are highly positively skewed. See the annexed image. Without going into details, it can be concluded from the sample that the tested, pretty straightforward test hypothesis can be accepted with certainty. However, what would be appropriate ways to visualize also the bodies of distributions from this type of discrete small-value data? In the image I added typical geom_boxplot from the ggplot2 R package without outliers and whiskers, to show the median, 1st and 3rd quartiles, to help the comprehension of the distributions. It somehow looks unintuitively "hollow" if only the individual measurements are shown (jittered slightly also along the y axis to ease the visual separation). Do you keep the geom_boxplot reasonable, or could you propose something else?

Found the proposal of violin charts from here: Analyzing/visualizing tightly grouped discrete results

I would say this is absolutely a fine visualization. (I would increase the horizontal distance a little so that each group is more clearly identifiable.) You could think about not plotting jittered single data points, but aligned blocks, since your data are discrete, which would essentially turn this into a kind of barplot-like thing. The boxes absolutely add value. You could also add horizontal lines to indicate each group's mean.

The box plot seems OK. I would try to make the median line more distinct from the quartile lines, perhaps make it a different color?  I'm not sure the violin plot would add much here, but you could try it and see. I also like Stephen's ideas; I think they would improve the plot. You could also try less horizontal jitter with smaller dot, or unfilled circles.

I agree with @StephanKolassa that a move towards a bar chart would be a good idea, as would adding means. I can't see much merit in showing quartiles. See my answer for more detail.

Your data are certainly positively skewed, as is expected. The adjective highly is uncalled for.

Box plots and jittering as a device can both be useful, but they are often used when other displays and devices would be as or more effective.
For completeness I note that a table of your data could work very well.
For outcomes that are discrete and indeed small integers, it is all too common that

The medians and quartiles may coincide, as seen here. That would be quite correct, but it is not helpful, and questions on CV show that it often confuses researchers and readers alike.

The medians and quartiles are each just one of the integer values and aren't sensitive to interesting or important differences between groups. (It is possible, depending on precise rules, that the calculated medians and quartiles have fractional parts.)


Box plots by default don't show means, which for small counted outcomes are natural summaries. Clearly, it should be easy in your favourite statistical software to add means to a graph. If not, you need a new favourite. If means are over-sensitive to outliers, then don't show them, or think of something else.
If box plots are adjunct to an analysis of variance or some similar method, showing means as well is surely not just advisable, but essential for completeness.
Jittering can be a useful device to shake apart points on scatter plots that otherwise would be over-plotted. I really can't follow why it's so popular in this context as a way of indicating frequency of discrete outcomes. That seems to call for analysis in terms of memetics, of following gurus without thinking hard about what works best for particular datasets. Jittering obliges readers to do repeated mental arithmetic to calculate local density or frequency. If you wish to indicate frequency, then indicate frequency directly. I have no objection to stripplots or dot plots, but it is easier to understand sets of points that are stacked, not jittered.
A fairly standard multiple bar chart or histogram should work well for your data. Adding small gaps between bars should be thought of as cosmetic or just one possible convention. If you think it's illogical or obnoxious, by all means let the bars touch. (Thin bars or spikes are just another convention with even bigger gaps.)
I would add means and medians for this kind of graph. I don't often find quartiles helpful for this kind of data, for the reasons given. Depending on the problem, the next step might be confidence intervals for means or medians.
Violin plots won't help much, if at all. Adding density estimates for small discrete outcomes would be a step in an irrelevant and unhelpful direction.  I am puzzled at the widespread acceptance of violin plots, which typically seem to be reported without explaining the density estimation protocol (including what happens if variables are bounded) and without any awareness that other choices of density estimation (e.g. kernel type and width, or non-kernel methods) would give different results. Relying on a violin plot routine's defaults to give the best answers for your data is often naive at best.
I passed on trying to count your points and just faked some broadly similar data. It would be easy enough to repeat the exercise for your real data.

How to do this in R is off-topic here. I used Stata. Here's my code for the record.
clear 
set obs 160 
set seed 314159
// _n is the observation number 
// result: blocks of 40 that are 1 2 3 4
gen type = ceil(_n/40) 

gen counts = . 

forval j = 1/4 { 
    replace counts = rbinomial(6, 1/(2 * `j')) if type == `j'
    label def type `j' "Type `j'", add 
}

label val type type 

egen mean = mean(counts), by(type)
egen median = median(counts), by(type)

// _N is the subscript of the last observation in each group 
bysort type : gen x = cond(_n==1, 0, cond(_n == _N, 20, .))

histogram counts, by(type, legend(pos(12)) note("") row(1)) horizontal freq discrete yla(0/6) ///
barw(0.8) lcolor(stc1*2) fcolor(stc1*0.1) xtitle(frequency) legend(order(2 3) row(1))  ///
addplot(line mean median x, lp(solid dash)) 

EDIT Another display, which I guess would be harder work for more readers, is a quantile plot. This would at least show the data directly and adjust automatically for groups of different sizes. Here fraction of data = (unique rank - 0.5) / group size, although other choices are defensible (yet would make no essential difference statistically).


I like your plot; flipping the axes seems to make it more readable. Does it rely on having the same (or very similar) number of data points per type? Would you change anything if the number of observations per group varied as well?

@dipetkov I am just using the axis choices in the question. Naturally anyone should flip the axes if that helps. If the number of data points was very different for each type, then as usual some thought needs to be given to showing proportions or percents instead. Being clear about the frequencies too is advisable.  If I see percents that are 50, 25, 25 I want to know if the frequencies are 2, 1, 1 or something else.

Thanks for all the participants so far. I will take these proposal into account and consider how to they fit into the other details and context. The vertically arranged bars are one clear and intuitive approach @NickCox. I hope this thread is also helpful to other people dealing with the same topic.
